# Virtual box ubuntu: Internet not detected on guest(Ubuntu) in host(winXp)

Tags: virtualbox, internet

Iam unable to get internet connection inside guest(ubuntu) in virtual box although host(WinXP) has an internet connection.
Tried with Nat: In Ubuntu it shows Wired connection connected but unable to browse sites.

Tried with Bridged adapter: In ubuntu it shows that wired connection is not connected.

Yes I use a proxy

I just appended the lines in the file.

"In the window that opens add the following lines modifying as appropriate to the file" can you explain what appropriate is. I am still not able to get connected to internet.

Comment: Have you installed guest additions?

Comment: hey what are the guest additions?

Comment: Take a look at this [Post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox).

Comment: Please post the output of `wget http://it.wikipedia.org` Does it return any error messages?

Comment: @ Mitch, Iam still not able to get the internet connectio after installing guest addtions
@ iqnis, it displays 503 error

Comment: Do you use a proxy from the windows machine?

Comment: Ravindra - you appear to have two accounts.  Please click the contact-us link at the bottom of this page and request that your two accounts are merged.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Step 1:

Open a terminal <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter

```
sudo -i;
```

You are now logged in as root so have the permissions required to save the files.  Keep the terminal open. Type:

```
gedit /etc/environment
```

In the window that opens add the following lines modifying as appropriate to the file.
By which I mean your proxy is probably not called `myproxy.server.com:8080` use the proxy settings from your windows machine.

```
http_proxy=http://myproxy.server.com:8080/
https_proxy=http://myproxy.server.com:8080/
ftp_proxy=http://myproxy.server.com:8080/
no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
HTTP_PROXY=http://myproxy.server.com:8080/
HTTPS_PROXY=http://myproxy.server.com:8080/
FTP_PROXY=http://myproxy.server.com:8080/
NO_PROXY="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
```

Save and close gedit.

Internet should now be working (next time you reboot) but you won't get any updates to fix this in the terminal you opened before type

```
gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/95proxies
```

A new window will open add the following lines modifying as appropriate

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://myproxy.server.com:8080/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://myproxy.server.com:8080/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://myproxy.server.com:8080/";
```

Save then close the terminal and reboot.  All should now work as expected.

Comment: Awesome! I wish I had seen this earlier - would have saved me hours of fiddling with it...

Answer (score 1):

I normally use Bridged. Do you have DHCP enabled in the network settings, so the VM gets an IP-address from the router or dhcp-server? Click the network icon and then Connection Information. See what IP-address the machine has. Is it on the same network as the host? If it's like 192.168.1.xx, can you ping to 192.168.1.1 (if the router has that address)? When I can't browse the internet, it normally means I use NAT for the VM, and it's IP-address is in the 10.x.x.x range. Unless your local network uses the same range, this means you have a local network for host-guest only.